# CollectionView on .NET Maui doesn't show columns after 13

Tags: c#, maui, collectionview

I have a CollectionView created that is binded by a property with 50+ fields. I setup the Collectionview with these settings and I am able to see the columns if I resize the WinUI.

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="53" 
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding BindDataRI}"
                        x:Name="CollectionViewData"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
```

I want to be able to display the horizontal data like an excel sheet that has 50+ rows with a scrollbar and resizes based on the WinUI App but it seems as though the data expands and I have to resize the WINUI to see all the data.  The tablet only can show 10-12 and even a wide monitor is unable to display it all.

I have tried to set HorizontalOptions to FillAndExpand but that doesnt fix the issue as well.

Comment: I would look for a commercial or open source DataGrid for MAUI.  Trying to make a CollectionView do this is probably not going to end well

Comment: Consider writing c# code to generate all the grid cells directly - no collectionview. Wrap that Grid in a ScrollView. Calculate appropriate values for column widths and row heights. Calculate Grid's HeightRequest and WidthRequest, and also set ScrollView's ContentSize to those values.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve as I am new to Xaml and this is inherited code - do you happen to have an example tutorial I can follow? I am interested in automating the generation of this view versus typing each bind out via the inherited method.

Comment: @enavuio there is no tutorial. This collection view, it uses different design patterns to optimize data presentation. It knows to load items when and if needed. It uses bindings. It uses view holder. There are so many bugs. So many... And this control is written by the right guys with the right knowledge. Still CollectionView is bug infested. You cannot do this alone. It is not realistic for someone new to write it. I do not agree with this suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CollectionView is vertical. Horizontally it is limited by the grid.
Grid is limited by the window width.

So your CollectionView is limited by the window.

This:

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
```

Wont do much.

You should do something like:

```
<HorizontalScroll>
   <VerticalCollectionView>
```

Btw, I have noticed this:

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="53"
```

I assume you are trying to put names over your columns.

Do you know that CollectionView has header and footer?
Perhaps you can check it out.

Comment: Is HorizontalScroll just pseudo code?

Comment: @enavuio yes. "Orientation, of type ScrollOrientation, represents the scrolling direction of the ScrollView. The default value of this property is Vertical" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview